# How to login (using both username and password) as a non root user in linux in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a non root user euser with a certain password.

I am also writting a shell script thru which first I need to login thru euser and then run a installer.

Shell script contents -

```
/bin/bash
su - newuser
cd installdir
./install.sh
```

When this script executes it gives error as -

```
Password:
su: Authentication failure**
```

How I can avoid this error and make my script work?

Comment: Why not just `su -c 'cd installdir; ./install.sh' - newuser` ?

Comment: You can always add `newuser` to the `wheel` group and set `visudo` options to allow `wheel` group members to execute `root` commands without a password via `sudo`. You can do the same for `su` by modifying your `/etc/pam.d/su` file and addition appropriate `auth` permissions allowing members of `wheel` to `su` w/o a password as well. Limit the members of wheel to only those required. Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/), [**Server Fault**](http://serverfault.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

su is for human interaction. try sudo for single commands.

Comment: You still can not pass a password for that

Comment: Is the password-authentication required? Otherwise just set NOPASSWD in the sudo-config. Or try  Expect.